# Can someone explain ActivityManager: Start proc 27854 (class)/u0a66 for service?

Tags: android, linux, process, android-activitymanager

Can someone please explain what is:

ActivityManager?

27854?

u0a66?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ActivityManager?

`ActivityManager` is one of the [system services](http://www.slideshare.net/opersys/understanding-the-android-system-server) started by the `system_server` process during *Android* boot up. `ActivityManager` is responsible for managing the application components (`Activities`, `Services`, `BroadcastReceivers`)

> 27854?

This is the Process Identifier ([PID](http://www.linfo.org/pid.html)).

> u0a66?

This is the User Identifier ([UID](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Research/paper/multi_user_most2014.pdf)). `u0` means the system supports multiple users (0 is for "primary" user), `a66` - is the application ID (66) set on its installation.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! So if we see something like Start proc XXXXX: (Class)/u0a66 for service (Class), or sometimes even a Start proc XXXXX: (package)/u0a66 for broadcast (Class), how can we explain  these two different examples?

Comment: @Reda M I guess, _"Start proc XXXXX: (Class)/u0a66 for service (Class)"_ means `ActivityManager` started a process due to a call to start/bind the service, while _"Start proc XXXXX: (package)/u0a66 for broadcast (Class)"_ means starting a process due to intent received by the broadcast receiver.

Comment: It means that the app was started when a service hosted within the app was launched (from some external code ) and in the second case it meant that your app launched in response to a broadcast. Rest of the identifiers in the log have already been explained by the answer